# Complex function that can't be extend

Tags: complex-analysis

Prove that exist a function $f:D\rightarrow C$ (where C is the set of complex numbers and $D=\{z\in C:|z-z_o|<r\}, \quad r>0$) that can't be extended analytically to $\partial D:=$ border of $D$

P.S. $f$ extend analytically in $z_0$ if exist $g$ analytic in $D\cup B(z_0)$ such that $f_D \equiv g$

Answer (score 1):

The easiest example is that of the pole on the boundary: function $1/(z-1)$ is analytic in the circle $|z|<1$ but is not bounded...

Answer (score 0):

Consider a lacunary series like
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty\Bigl( \frac{z-z_0}{r}\Bigr)^{2^k}.
$$